# Creating BufferedReader to read URL causing error: Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, urlconnection

I am trying to read the content of a URL. The initialization of the BufferedReader keeps causing the crash.

I've tried looking up peoples' solutions, but no matter what I do, I get this error.

Here is my code:

```
 try {
        String sUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        System.out.println("About to create URL.");
        URL url = new URL(sUrl);
        System.out.println("Created URL");

        System.out.println("About to create URLConnection");
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        System.out.println("Created URLConnection");

        System.out.println("About to create the BufferedReader");
        BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Created the BufferedReader");

        System.out.println("About to create a StringBuilder");
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("Created StringBuilder");

        int byteRead;
        System.out.println("About to enter while loop and build string");
        while ((byteRead = bR.read()) != -1)
        {
            sBuilder.append((char) byteRead);
        }
        System.out.println("Built string");

        bR.close();
        System.out.println("Buffered reader is closed");
        String text = sBuilder.toString();
        System.out.println(text);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
//
}
```

And here are (some of) the logs I get:

```
07-24 13:56:17.546: I/System.out(1554): About to create URL.
07-24 13:56:17.557: I/System.out(1554): Created URL
07-24 13:56:17.557: I/System.out(1554): About to create URLConnection
07-24 13:56:17.557: I/System.out(1554): Created URLConnection
07-24 13:56:17.557: I/System.out(1554): About to create the BufferedReader
07-24 13:56:17.576: D/AndroidRuntime(1554): Shutting down VM
07-24 13:56:17.576: W/dalvikvm(1554): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   
                                      (group=0x40a13300)
07-24 13:56:17.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 13:56:17.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 
                                     activity ComponentInfo{com. ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Android 3.0, It is not legal to open a url connection in the main UI Thread. You **MUST** do this in an AsyncTask/Background thread.

Comment: As of Android 3.0, you cannot make any network connections such as HTTP and POST on the UI thread. You'll have to do that in the background.

Comment: This makes sense. Need to research this stuff more.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I used to test on 2.1 and it was working .. then when I opened the app on 4.0 it didnt work. Your answer really helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Its always advisable to keep the **UI work on UI thread, and Non-UI work on Non-UI thread,** that became a **law from HoneyComb version of Android**.

**Moreover try the below code....**

```
public final String sUrl = "http://www.google.com";

new Thread(new Runnable(){

public void run(){

URL url = new URL(sUrl);

InputStream i = url.openStream();

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String s = null;

while ((br.readLine())!=null){

  sb.append(br.readLine());

  }

  s = sb.toString();

 System.out.println(s);

     }
   }).start();
```

**2.** This code could have been smaller with just `InputStream and Scanner`, **but as you have mentioned** `BufferedReader`, **i used it**...

**3.** You can also use `AsyncTask` specially designed for android, know as **painless thread, which easily synchronizes the UI and Non-UI thread.**

Comment: Using an AsyncTask would probably be the standard.

Comment: Ya it is..thats know as painless threading.... but here the probs was abt not able to get the output.... and till HoneyComb its allowed..so even if the UI would have been non-responsive...the output must be obtained.. But if you think that will make a diff i will add it..